# Purpose of using octal for ASCII

Tags: c, octal

Why would a C programmer use escape sequences (oct/hex) for ASCII values rather than decimal?

Follow up: does this have to do with either performance or portability?

Example:

```
char c = '\075';
```

Comment: `8` is not a legal octal digit, is it?

Comment: no it's not, not at all

Comment: When the code read `'\085'`, it was a multi-character character constant with a null followed by digit 8 and digit 5, which would lead to all sorts of weirdness.  Multi-character character constants have an implementation-defined interpretation, and assigning one to a plain `char` (instead of perhaps a plain `int`) leads to confusion.  GCC gave errors (because I compile with `-Werror`): `x.c:2:10: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]`
 and
`x.c:2:10: error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use octal or hexadecimal because there isn't a way to specify decimal codes inside a character literal or string literal.  Octal was prevalent in PDP-11 code.  These days, it probably makes more sense to use hexadecimal, though `'\0'` is more compact than `'\x0'` (so use `'\0'` when you null terminate a string, etc.).

Also, beware that `"\x0ABad choice"` doesn't have the meaning you might expect, whereas `"\012007 wins"` probably does.  (The difference is that a hex escape runs on until it comes across a non-hex digit, whereas octal escapes stop after 3 digits at most.  To get the expected result, you'd need `"\x0A" "Bad choice"` using 'adjacent string literal concatenation'.)

And this has nothing to do with performance and very little to do with portability.  Writing `'\x41'` or `'\101'` instead of `'A'` is a way of decreasing the portability and readability of your code.  You should only consider using escape sequences when there isn't a better way to represent the character.

Comment: Are you implying that "\012007" will stop after 3 digits, and be equivalent to "\012" ?

Comment: It is a 9-character string, the first character of which is `'\012'`, which is also known as control-L and is usually equivalent to `'\f'` (form-feed); the remainder is `"007 wins"`.  So yes, octal escapes stop after at most 3 octal digits, but hex escapes stop at the first non-hex digit.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not have anything to do with performance and portability. It is just one convenient way to define character literals and to use in string literal specially for non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with performance nor portability.  In fact, you don't need any codes at all, instead of this:

```
char c = 65;
```

You can simply write:

```
char c = 'A';
```

But some characters are not so easy to type, e.g. ASCII SOH, so you might write:

```
char c = 1; // SOH
```

Or any other form, hexadecimal, octal, depending on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with performance nor with portability. It is simply that the ASCII character set (as are its derivatives up to UTF) is organized in bytes and bits. For example, the 32 first characters are the control characters, 32 = 040 = 0x20, ASCII code of 'A' is 65 = 0101 = 0x41 and 'a' is 97 = 0141 = 0x61, ASCII code of '0' is 48 = 060 = 0x30.

I do not know for you, but for me '0x30' and 0x'41' are easier to remember and use in manual operations than 48 and 65.

By the way a byte represents exactly all value between 0 and 255 that is 0 and 0xFF ...

Comment: Thank you for pointing how ASCII aligns bit boundaries with the sets of control-characters, digits, lowercase and uppercase.  It aligns with octal most neatly of all: Codes less than \100 are mainly non-letters, the second half of which are mainly digits. Codes above \100 are mainly letters, the second half of which are mainly lowercase. Control-characters match uppercase letters by simply ignoring uppercase's leading digit 1.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this works.

But I got immediatly a pretty usefull idea for it.

Imagin you have got a low memory enviroment and have to use a permission system like the unix folder permissions.

Lets say there are 3 groups and for each group 2 different options which can be allowed or denied.

0 means none of both options,

1 means first option allowed,

2 means second option allowed and

3 means both allowed.

To store the permissions you could do it like:

```
char* bar = "213"; // first group has allowed second option, second group has first option allowed and third has full acces.
```

But there you have four byte storage for that information.

Ofc you could just convert that to decimal notation. But thats less readable.

But now as I know this....

doing:

```
char bar = '\0213';
```

Is pretty readable and also saving memory!
I love it :D